# Cannot get simplest cocoapod library to work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I tried to make this work for me now for a long time, because I believe I am doing something ridiculously wrong. I followed the steps in [using-pod-lib-create](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create) to create a swift pod. I did not choose to use a test framework to remove complexity. After, I added some ViewController subclass into the place under *Development Pods* (MyLib/Pod/Classes/SomeViewController.swift). 
My Problem now: I cannot reference this controller from within my AppDelegate. I can import the "MyLib" module and XCode will argue when I write that wrong, so I figure XCode is finding the module. Though I cannot use the controller which is inside that module. I did *pod install* a couple of times, checked the podspec, linted the podspec until all was fine, even the license. I cannot make it work. I also tried it with an ObjC-Pod-Configuration, but that also didn't work. Some time ago I did the same thing and it worked (for Swift using ObjC-Development-Pod) out of the box, so I am really confused by now. Can somebody give me another hint what it could be?

I am using XCode 6.3.2 and Cocoapods 0.37.2

Thanks a million
Jörn

**Edit:**

My current podspec for this question. For the real world problem I had a more sophisticated one, which also did not work

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyLib"
  s.version          = "0.1.0"
  s.summary          = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr"
  s.description      = <<-DESC
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                   DESC
  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/MyLib"
  # s.screenshots     = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Jörn Schmidt" => "schmidt@devid.net" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/MyLib.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{swift}'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyLib' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Comment: Can you show your .podspec? BTW. If you're adding your library from iOS 8 (possible with Swift) I'd go into Carthage - much easier to use both via developer and user, provides more control and is faster.

Comment: @Vive I edited my post. I thought about carthage but I have to also support cocoapods

Comment: I think your path is indicating subfolders instead of folders, but I'm not sure. Can you check `s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/*.swift'`?

Comment: no that didn't help, besides this shoul state any swift-file in any subfolder recursively

Answer (score 0):

Found out that pod install is not enough as I needed to "clear the cache" which is deleting the Podfile.lock and Pods/Manifest.lock first.

So for me this worked:
- create the pod as a framework first
- then add the podspec and fill out all information
- in the app project I add the lib as a local pod dependency (Development Pod)
- always when I make changes to the lib from within the app project I switch to the lib project, build it, execute `rm -f Pods/Manifest.lock && rm -f Podfile.lock && pod install` in the app dir
- tada: it works. I didn't find any better way so far, it is kinda not straight forward I think, but it's better than *!#